# Does Apache web service restart close existing MySQL connections?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php

In the case of 'too many connections' error, if I do a `service httpd restart/reload`, would it free up the existing MySQL connections?

Is it possible that when restarting Apache, Apache closes the DB Connections but does not inform mysqld.

Note: mysqld has wait_timeout = 8 hours.

Comment: You may want to run `mysql -B --raw -e "select concat('KILL ',id,';') from information_schema.processlist where Command =    'Sleep' AND user = 'root'" | tail -n 2 | xargs -0 -I {} mysql -e "{}"` instead to kill sleeping processes, which are probably the cause of your problems...  (actually the cause is badly written application, but fixing it is far beyond scope of this question)

Comment: @Anubioz that will not fix the problem, that will just kill (potentially genuinely) sleeping connections. The actual fix is to debug the script causing the problems, to do otherwise is just lazy.

Comment: @CraigWatson Well, killing apache was already lazy, directly killing sleeping transactions is a faster way to achieve exactly the same result, which OP wanted to get by restarting apache. Yes, I know that's bad, but actually debugging application can take months. And during that time killing sleeping processes is a better way to make that app reachable than killing apache :) (very important addition - that is assuming there is absolutely nothing else accessing database, besides that webserver :)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes, but not directly. In any case, I would consider reducing your MySQL `wait_timeout` to something more realistic like 30 seconds.

Apache is a web-server, it accepts HTTP connection requests and serves content back to the client - it cannot natively connect to a MySQL database.

The most likely source of your connections is an application which generates responses to those requests, i.e. a PHP, Java, Python, etc - you've tagged your question with `php` so I'll assume PHP here.

Now, also assuming you use Apache's mod_php rather than PHP-FPM, then PHP processes are forked by Apache, and so when you restart Apache, these processes are killed and respawned. If you were running PHP-FPM, restarting Apache would not kill any PHP processes as FPM runs as its own daemon.

In the case of a PHP process being killed via mod_php, it does not call `mysql_close()` to close the connection directly, and so the connection will be kept open for `wait_timeout` seconds.

You can tell Apache to do a "graceful" restart and allow existing threads to exit before termination, using `service httpd graceful` or `apachectl -k graceful`.

However, if your PHP code is not closing the connection via `mysql_close()` then that will be the ultimate source of your problem and restarting Apache via any method will not solve the issue.

Also, an important distinction to make with `restart` vs `reload` - the former terminates processes, the latter simply reloads configuration. If you really want to terminate processes, use `restart`.